# How to return nil from a TextField?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am trying to return `nil` if the `TextField` is empty.

This is my code:

```
import SwiftUI

func ??<T>(lhs: Binding<Optional<T>>, rhs: T) -> Binding<T> {
    Binding(get: { lhs.wrappedValue ?? rhs },
            set: { lhs.wrappedValue = $0 })
}

struct SomeView: View {
    
    @State private var string: String?
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("Enter something", text: $string ?? "")
            
            Text(string ?? "This string is nil.")
        }
        
    }
}
```

I am trying to get a `nil` value if the `TextField` is empty, but instead it just returns an empty string. How can I go about returning `nil` instead of an empty string? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you can explain your use case so you might use a different solution.

Comment: @Tbi My use case is that I would like to store a value on an `@State var` if the user inputs something on the text field. If there is nothing, I would like to return a nil value, so I can use optional wrapping to display a default value.